# Movie Clips Position Changes when user Backs out of Android AIR Game

Tags: android, actionscript-3, position, positioning, stage

Hey guys so I am having this strange issue with my Android AIR Game.

So everything on the game is aligned perfect but the problem that I am having is when say the user backs out of the app and then goes back into the app to continue playing the movie clips completely reposition themselves to the bottom right of the screen. They dont scale out of proportion or anything but just reposition. I dont understand why this is happening? This is currently what I use to scale everything for Android devices:

```
//Screen size for all devices
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        trace(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
```

This code has always worked for me but say the user leaves the app and when they come back this Movie Clip or current movie clips:

```
        loadingScreen = new mcLoadingScreen();
        stage.addChild(loadingScreen);
        loadingScreen.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        loadingScreen.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
```

will be repositioned to the bottom Right hand side of the screen. Any ideas? Thanks for any help I appreciate it!

Also I seemed to narrow it down. This only happens when the user presses the Home button and the screen orientation goes from Landscape which I have it set as, to Portrait. So when I go back into the app after that, all the Movie clips are re positioned

Comment: Have you tried using `stage.fullScreenWidth` instead of `stage.stageWidth` in your second code?

Comment: I have not tried that. I will definitely do so if that might fix the issue?

Comment: No that didnt seem to do anything. It made it worse actually. When I add that line the sceen disappears.

Comment: Have you tried isolating the problem by creating a very simple app that has just one simple sprite and does nothing else? If it works, then the problem is somewhere else. Also, trace all possible coords and sizes at the moment the error happens: x, y, width, height of the Stage, sprites, etc. Some of the values must be wrong, once you know which is wrong, you can trace it further.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the advice I will definitely do so.

Comment: I'm pretty lost now. I cant understand what could be happening. This problem only happens on certain devices. Happens frequently on newer android devices. Whenever my interstitial ad pops up and the user clicks out of it and goes back to the game everything is completely repositioned.

Comment: It almost sounds like the stage align is getting reset to default (center). If so, you could try resetting the stage align and scale mode on `Event.ACTIVATE`.

Comment: So on the Event.ACTIVATE just recall the same code above in that Activate function?

Comment: I tried something like that but maybe I didnt do it correctly. I had it set in my NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate )

Comment: Yes that's the basic idea, on `Event.Activate` reset all the stage setup code. I usually use `Event.ACTIVATE` on `stage`, but it is a "broadcast" event so it should get dispatched by any event dispatcher, so `NativeApplication.nativeApplication` should work.

Comment: Okay So I am getting close to solving it. You were right @Aaron about the 'Event.ACTIVATE' I just added the same code and repositioned the main screen Movie Clips back to stage.Width/2 etc... Whats going on now is when I back out of the app and go back in everything is still messed up but if i back out again and go back in everything repositions itself perfect. So I have to back out twice in order to fix the issue. Dont really understand why its doing this but ill try figuring it out. Thanks everyone. If you have any ideas why this is happening I would still love to hear them.

Comment: Ok, a couple more things I would try: 1) listen for `Event.RESIZE` on `stage` and reset those properties. 2) On `Event.DEACTIVATE` set `stage.displayState` back to `NORMAL`, and then in `Event.ACTIVATE` back to `FULL_SCREEN` (`FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`?). 3) Try calling the reset in all these cases from within a `setTimeout()`, or `stage.invalidate()` and `Event.RENDER`.

Comment: One last thing: you mention that this only happens with "newer Android devices" -- can you collect what version of Android? And what AIR SDK are you using? If not the latest AIR SDK, I would update it. Android 5.0 is pretty recent and required compatibility updates to AIR.

Comment: Alright I will definitely give that a try later on today. Ill let you know how everything goes. Yeah the data shows that this only happens with devices running android 4.4 and up. I am currently using AIR SDK Version 16.0. But I see they just updated it to 17.0.

Comment: I know when I was using older versions of AIR this never happened.

Comment: Alright finally fixed the problem. Thanks everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these configurations (I'm not telling that will fix the problem, just suggesting something that worked for me with an iOS device):

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
// stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

in your Application Descriptor (XML file)

```
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
```

If doesn't work, probably what @Aaron suggested will the the start to solve this issue:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, function(event:Event):void
{
      // the application is reactivated 
});

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, function(event:Event):void
{
      // the application is deactivate to receive a phone call or when the user presses the Home button, etc
});
```

Add some traces and verify what changes. If you have events listeners like ENTER_FRAME, Event.RESIZE, be aware and remove these event listeners when the application is deactivate.

Hope will be possible to help you somehow.